# Python pandas formatação

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
ID = [i for i in range(1,101)]
def tabela(imc):
    if imc < 18.5:
        return 'Abaixo do peso'
    elif imc < 25 and imc >= 18.5:
        return 'Saudável'
    elif imc < 30 and imc >= 25:
        return 'Acima do peso'
    elif imc < 35 and imc >= 30:
        return 'Obesidade grau I'
    elif imc < 40 and imc >= 35:
        return 'Obesidade grau II'
    else:
        return 'Obesidade grau III'

pd.options.display.max_rows = 999
altura, peso=np.loadtxt('data.csv',delimiter=':',dtype='float',unpack=True)
imc = peso/altura**2
classificacao = []
for i in imc:
    classificacao.append(tabela(i))
data = {'Altura' : altura,
        'Peso' : peso,
        'IMC' : imc,
        'Classificação': classificacao,
        'Chamada':chamada}

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ['Altura','Peso','IMC','Classificação'],index=data['ID'])
decimal = pd.Series([2,2,1],index=['Altura','Peso','IMC'])
df.sort_values(by='IMC')
print(df.round(decimal))
```

tabela/output:

- Altura  | Peso  | IMC   |   Classificação
- 1      1.88 | 91.45 | 25.8  |    Acima do peso
- 2      1.82 | 95.65 | 29.0  |    Acima do peso
- 3      1.88 | 94.01 | 26.5  |    Acima do peso
- 4      1.74 | 63.55 | 21.0  |         Saudável
- 5      1.69 | 66.12 | 23.1  |         Saudável
- 6      1.75 | 68.84 | 22.5  |         Saudável
- 7      1.75 | 82.72 | 26.9  |    Acima do peso

.....

Os valores só estão formatados deste jeito devido ao pd.round(decimal), porém, eu gostaria de usar outra formatação junto a essa que seria o pd.sort_values(by='IMC'). Não consigo usar os dois ao mesmo tempo e depois imprimir já reformatado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fala Thomas Caio, tudo certo?

Acredito que tu poderia incluir a linha "df.sort_values(by='IMC')"  a uma variável, e em seguida aplicar o "round" em cima desta variável junto ao print,  ficando:

```
novodf = df.sort_values(by='IMC')
print(novodf.round(decimal))
```

Caso eu esteja me equivocando diga ae, abraço.